# Selenium Tests Failing when running them all in one go

Tags: selenium

I have the below code which initiates the browser in each test. However the first Test runs OK correctly starting the browser. The second Test on wards start to fail

```
 public class BrowserFactory


        {      
        private static IWebDriver driver;
        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.");
                return driver;
            }
            set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
        {
            switch (browserName)
            {
                case "Firefox":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                    }
                    break;

                case "IE":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                    }
                    break;

                case "Chrome":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new ChromeDriver();
                        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                    }
                    break;
            }
}
```

And this is how I initiate and quit browser in each test

[TestFixture]

```
public class AdminUserHasAccessToDashboard

{

    [SetUp]
    public void GotoHomePage()
    {
        BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
        BrowserFactory.LoadApplication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Quit()
    {
        BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();

    }
```

Comment: how are you calling the driver from your tests. are you initialising a new browser instance for each new test as that could possibly be your issue

Comment: Please tell us specifically how the subsequent tests fail.  What is the error?

Comment: fails to open the browser followed by OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:62277

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are probably setting driver instance in your first test and other tests are false on `if (driver == null)`, so other instances will never be created. Your code is incomplete so I can't be sure, but it seems to be an issue here. 
How are you closing your driver after first test is completed?

Comment: public static void CloseAllDrivers()
        {

            driver.Quit();
            
         }

Comment: And when is this method called?

Comment: in the teardown section of each test

Comment: Well I can't see your implementation of teardown section so it's impossible to help you.

Comment: `[SetUp]
        public void OpenFizz()
        {
            BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
            BrowserFactory.LoadApplication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void QuitTest()
        {
            BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
        }

        [Test]
        public void UserWithRightPermissionsCanAccessActionPlanning()
        {
            
          }
    }
}`

Comment: Are you sure that your teardown method `QuitTest()` is really called after every test?

Answer (score 0):

Include the method mentioned below in your browser factory and call at the end of each test, or set up before the tests are run then use the single instance for each test and tear down at the end.

```
public static void Quit(){
   if (Driver!= null)
       Driver.Quit();
}
```

I use a static "Driver" class which is referenced in each test class (not each test case)

I include this in each class(they are nunit C# tests)

```
#region Initialise and clean up

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Init()
{
    Driver.Initialise();
}

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void CleanUp()
{
    Driver.Quit();
}

#endregion
```

Then my driver class is as below, the appstate region wont apply but can be edited to suit your needs.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using AdaptiveAds_TestFramework.PageFrameworks;

namespace AdaptiveAds_TestFramework.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains functionality for browser automation.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Driver
    {
        #region Variables

        private static IWebDriver _instance;
        private static Period _waitPeriod;

        #endregion//Variables

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Browser automation object.
        /// </summary>
        public static IWebDriver Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
            set { _instance = value; SetWait(WaitPeriod); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Duration automation framework must wait before throwing an error.
        /// </summary>
        public static Period WaitPeriod
        {
            get { return _waitPeriod; }
            set
            {
                _waitPeriod = value;
                SetWait(_waitPeriod);
            }
        }

        #endregion//Properties

        #region Methods

        #region set-up and tear-down

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up a new automation object.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Initialise()
        {
            Quit();
            Instance = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(ConfigData.FireFoxPath), new FirefoxProfile());
            Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            WaitPeriod = ConfigData.DefaultWaitPeriod;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes of the automation object.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Quit()
        {
            if (Instance != null)
                Instance.Quit();
        }

        #endregion //set-up and tear-down

        #region NavigableLocations

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigate browser to a given location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="location">Location to navigate to.</param>
        /// <param name="logInIfNeeded">Logs in if authentication is required.</param>
        /// <param name="errorIfNotReached">Errors if the location was not reached.</param>
        public static void GoTo(Location location, bool logInIfNeeded, bool errorIfNotReached)
        {
            // Navigate browser to the location.
            Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(Helper.RouteUrl(location));
            Thread.Sleep(500);// wait for system to navigate
            bool needToLogIn = false;
            if (logInIfNeeded)
            {
                try
                {
                    IsAt(Location.Login);
                    needToLogIn = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Not at login page so Login not needed.
                }
                if (needToLogIn)
                {
                    LoginPage.LoginAs(ConfigData.Username).WithPassword(ConfigData.Password).Login();
                    GoTo(location, false, errorIfNotReached);
                }
            }
            if (errorIfNotReached)
            {
                IsAt(location);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures the Driver is at the specified location, throws a WebDriverException if at another location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="location">Location to check the browser is at.</param>
        public static void IsAt(Location location)
        {
            string expected = Helper.RouteUrl(location);
            string actual = Instance.Url;

            // Check the browser is at the correct location.
            if (actual != expected)
            {
                // Driver is not at the specified location.
                throw new WebDriverException("Incorrect location.",
                    new InvalidElementStateException(
                        "The given location did not match the browser." +
                        " Expected \"" + expected + "\" Actual \"" + actual + "\""));
            }
            ActionWait(Period.None, CheckForLavarelError);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures the Driver is not at the specified location, throws a WebDriverException if at the location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="location">Location to check the browser is not at.</param>
        public static void IsNotAt(Location location)
        {
            string expected = Helper.RouteUrl(location);
            string actual = Instance.Url;

            // Check the browser is not at the correct location.
            if (actual == expected)
            {
                // Driver is at the specified location.
                throw new WebDriverException("Incorrect location.",
                            new InvalidElementStateException(
                                "The given location matched the browser."));
            }
        }

        #endregion//NavigableLocations

        #region WaitHandling

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs an action with a temporary wait period.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="waitPeriod">Period to wait while executing action.</param>
        /// <param name="action">Action to execute.</param>
        public static void ActionWait(Period waitPeriod, Action action)
        {
            // Store the current wait period
            Period previousPeriod = WaitPeriod;
            // Run task with given wait period
            SetWait(waitPeriod);
            action();
            // Revert to the old wait period
            SetWait(previousPeriod);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the Automation instance wait period.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="waitPeriod">New wait period.</param>
        private static void SetWait(Period waitPeriod)
        {
            int miliseconds;
            ConfigData.WaitPeriods.TryGetValue(waitPeriod, out miliseconds);

            // Set the drivers instance to use the wait period.
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds));
            }
        }

        #endregion//WaitHandling

        #region AppState

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks that the website hasn't crashed from the back end.
        /// </summary>
        public static void CheckForLavarelError()
        {
            bool error = false;
            try
            {
                Instance.FindElement(By.ClassName("exception_message"));
                error = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                // all good, could not find error content.
            }
            if (error)
            {
                throw new Exception("Lavarel threw an error");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clicks on the main menu button to open or close the main menu.
        /// </summary>
        public static void OpenCloseMenuBar()
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement menuButton = Instance.FindElement(By.Name(ConfigData.MainMenuButtonName));
                menuButton.Click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw new NoSuchElementException("Could not find the Menu button element.", e);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asserts the logged in state agents the parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="checkLoggedIn">Parameter to check agents logged in state.</param>
        public static void LoggedIn(bool checkLoggedIn)
        {
            OpenCloseMenuBar();

            bool signInFound;
            bool signOutFound;
            bool isLoggedIn = false;

            try { Instance.FindElement(By.Name(ConfigData.SignInName)); signInFound = true; }
            catch { signInFound = false; }
            try { Instance.FindElement(By.Name(ConfigData.SignOutName)); signOutFound = true; }
            catch { signOutFound = false; }

            if (!signInFound && !signOutFound)
            {
                throw new ElementNotVisibleException("Unable to assert state due to unavailability of SignIn/Out links.");
            }

            if (signOutFound) isLoggedIn = true;
            if (signInFound) isLoggedIn = false;

            if (isLoggedIn != checkLoggedIn)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Logged in Expected: {checkLoggedIn} Actual: {isLoggedIn}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Signs out of the system.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="errorIfAlreadySignedOut">Determines whether to throw an error if already signed out.</param>
        public static void SignOut(bool errorIfAlreadySignedOut = true)
        {
            try
            {
                LoggedIn(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (errorIfAlreadySignedOut)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return;
            }

            IWebElement signOut = Instance.FindElement(By.Name(ConfigData.SignOutName));
            signOut.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(500);// wait for system to logout
        }

        #endregion//AppState

        #endregion//Methods
    }
}
```

Comment: I have now created the following method in my browser factory  and then called  it in all my tests in the Teardown Still no Joy :(                                          `public static void CloseAllDrivers()
        {
            if (driver != null)
                driver.Quit();
            
        }`

Comment: I imagine it is probably trying to open a new browser before the last one has closed, that is most probably the cause of your issue.
try using them in a one time setup and one time teardown rather than for each test as not only will it be less likely to cause you issues but it will speed up your tests and reduce the amount of memory held by the browser (especially if you're using chrome)